# How to check that the audio files in a directory match the file names stored in a database

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I have a database that contains the pathway to audio files. This data is stored in a column called Language1. The actual audio file is stored in a folder called Language1.

I want to check that the pathways in the database match the filename that is in the directory.

The first 10 files are in the folder, but the code is not recognising that. I want the code to read through each row in the database and compare that with the file names in the folder.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "xxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $password, $dbname);
$query = "SELECT Language1 FROM Table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

$path = "/file/to/path/English/$Language1"; 
$Language1 = $row['Language1'];

if (file_exists($path)) 
    { 
 echo "The file $Language1 exists<br/>";
        } 
else
    { *
    echo "The file $Language1 does not exist<br/>";
    } 
} 
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: you just need to confirm the successful file upload.  This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793633/check-if-file-uploaded-successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First generate the relative file path of each file from your working directory to the folder where the audio files are uploaded. then check if that file exist using the *file_exists* function. You can update the status of each files to a column in the table.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php.

*Edited - sample code*

```
$username = "Name";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $filename = $row['filename'];
        $path = "/folder/".$username."/english/". $filename; 
    if (file_exists($path)) { 
        echo "The file $filename exists"; 
    } else { 
        echo "The file $filename does not exist";
    } 
    }
```

Comment: That makes sense, and will use the file_exist function. However, I will not know how many files a customer might upload, I therefore cannot write down the pathways of the audio files. I ideally need a button/form that they can press that will then check the database and directory.

Comment: You should create directories with the username of each customer. then you can use that to generate the path of the uploaded file.

Comment: Yes that will work. Excuse my ignorance and lack of knowledge (I started this little project with no php experience). I will create User1, they will have subfolder 1.1English 1.2French. The same for user 2 and user 3. How do i do the next part of what you are suggesting, can you provide a starting point please.

Comment: $path = "\folder\".$username."\english\". $filename;
if (file_exists($path)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. Finally, to check that  the filename ALSO exists in the database (using MAMP), do i need to run a MySQL query to say look in table 1, does $path exist in each row?

Comment: answer updated. you have to update the code according to your requirement.

Comment: Very helpful. Because I have several tables in my database do i need $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM......) to ensure that the code looks to read the information from the right table?

Comment: Yes you have to select that table and get the results in the loop as shown in the sample code . you have to change the code based on your requirement.